# How can I copy a cell from google sheet and paste in another place with power automate desktop?

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I have tried to select the cell with UI element but its not working. The specified cell not getting selected. UI element only selecting the whole google sheet, but not the specified cell. How can I copy the specified cell? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Google Sheets API seen here https://power.automate.gallery/write-to-google-sheets-api-using-oauth-2-0-power-automate-for-desktop
Another option which might be easier is using the Power Automate cloud version which I believe has a google sheets connector built in.